# symfony 3 knp paginator composer file not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, knppaginator, symfony-3.3

I'm building a blog in symfony 3 and Sonata.
I'd like to use knp paginator so I put that command :

`require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`

It gives me that error :

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in
> ```
>
> phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php
>   on line 220

So I did that :

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle
```

This gives me that :

> ```
> Could not open input file: composer
> ```

If I just add the line in my composer.json and run composer update, it gives me the same error of size, if I add "php -d memory_limit = -1" it tells me "could not open input file : composer"
I did not have this error before, I've already use that "php -d memory limit" and it worked fine, I don't know what to do anymore I need that paginator bundle for my project
Does anybody have any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happen when you use a globally installed `composer.phar` files. So You should (1) locate the absolute path of the installed composer file then (2) use the absolute path in the php usage, as example:

> ```
> ~ ᐅ php -d memory_limit=-1 composer
> Could not open input file: composer
> ~ ᐅ which composer
> /usr/local/bin/composer
> ~ ᐅ php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer
>    ______
>   / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
>  / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
> / /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
> \____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
>                     /_/
> Composer version 1.4.1 2017-03-10 09:29:45
> ```

Hope this help